# Logism: Further reducing number of logic gates in a circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have this circuit attached below that has an arbitrary behavior. I want to reduce the number of gates more if possible. I've taken its expression and passed it through multiple boolean expression minimizers but I am wondering if it is possible to condense it even more, possibly using some other component. Could anyone offer any advice? For the image, don't worry about there being a separate input for the negation, it's because this is a subcircuit and it's being fed both forms. Boolean expression:

(¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬C ∨ ¬D) ∧ (A ∨ B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ B ∨ D) ∧ (¬B ∨ ¬C ∨ ¬D)

[image]

Comment: What's the output or truth table for that circuit? Perhaps that can help to simplify it. Also you could use a mux as a look-up table if you just want to draw less gates.

Comment: Since you are using Logisim, are you aware of its optimization capabilities? -- What methods did you try? Did you read any material about minimizing logic?